# Numpy Loadtxt won't import my 2 data columns

Tags: python, numpy

I have a text file with two columns of data that are separated by a comma. I am trying to import the data into my python script using numpy loadtext, but I am getting the error: invalid literal for float(): 201.9271,43

All of my data looks like this. How do can I get numpy loadtext to import the data properly?

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np 

data = np.loadtxt('Ozone_at_Uva_2001.txt', dtype=object)

dct = data[:,0] #DecTime 

ppbv = data[:,1] #[O3]ppbv
```

My text file looks like this except for there are many more data points.

```
201.9271,43

201.9375,35

201.9479,31

201.9583,35

201.9688,31

201.9792,30
```

Comment: Use `delimiter=','`.  The default delimiter is white space, not a comma.

Comment: Why are you using `dtype='object'`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `genfromtxt` might work:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt('Ozone_at_Uva_2001.txt', delimiter=',')
dct = data[:,0]
ppbv = data[:,1]
print dct
print ppbv
```

Output:

```
[ 201.9271  201.9375  201.9479  201.9583  201.9688  201.9792]
[ 43.  35.  31.  35.  31.  30.]
```

If you wanna use `loadtxt`, generally like this:

```
data2 = np.loadtxt('Ozone_at_Uva_2001.txt', delimiter=',')
print data2
```